# Show post title and custom fields in sidebar with shortcode in widget - Wordpress

Tags: plugins, wordpress, custom-fields, shortcode

I would like to show certain data in the HTML/text widget with shortcodes.

I already made the include php call in my functions.php:

```
function event_widget($atts) {

// turn on output buffering to capture script output

ob_start();

// include file (contents will get saved in output buffer)

include("wp-content/themes/mytheme/widgets/event.php");

// save and return the content that has been output

$content = ob_get_clean();
return $content;
}
//register the Shortcode handler
add_shortcode('event', 'event_widget');
```

It gets the data to the widget if I put just plain text to event.php, so the call is done correctly, but I don't know how to write the event.php to get this data:

```
// the loop
<?php if (have_posts()) :
        while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<ul>
<li>
<?php if( get_post_meta($post->ID, "customfield1", true) ): ?>
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "customfield1", true); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</li>

<li>
<?php if( get_post_meta($post->ID, "customfield2", true) ): ?>
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "customfield2", true); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
global $post;
echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "customfield1", true);
echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "customfield2", true);
```

If you echo a value that is false it will amount to '' (nothing) so you don't have to check if they are set.

Answer (score 0):

And also this works perfect:

```
<?php
global $post;

$args = array('category' => 37, 'post_type' => 'post' ); 
$postslist = get_posts( $args ); 
foreach ($postslist as $post) : setup_postdata($post); 
?> 
<?php if( get_post_meta($post->ID, "customfield1", true) ): ?>
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "customfield1", true); ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Is anything "wrong" with this code?